# Barclays ePDQ and PHP - Handling Post?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

So this is my second post about Barclay's ePDQ, which in all fairness isn't brilliant.

I have everything working and I can make payments fine, the problem is, how do you handle the posting back of the data?

I have the `returnurl` defined, with just a `var_dump($_POST)` as i thought it would post the information back.

There's no where in the docs that mention how to handle this information correctly, just a bit of code, with no explanation of how to implement it.

Could someone explain to me, how I get this information into my returnurl, so i can do the database updates I need to flag that the order has been paid for?

Thank you

Comment: You could use a mail function in your payment handler and see what has been send (either through $_POST or $_GET).

Comment: I found a code example (http://pastie.org/2385110), but this again, doesn't seem to display the POST data back from ePDQ.

Comment: Ok, so it seems, that the `returnurl` only passes back the oid. How would I get the POST data in this page?

Comment: You should be able to use `print_r($_POST);`, but are you sure data is really send to that page?

Comment: Well, in the docs it says only the oid is passed to the returnurl. So I'm not sure how I'd access the `$_POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be doing the database updates using the secure post-back. That happens separately from the redirect to your site. From the docs :

"The Post URL is ‘called’ by the CPI after the authorisation of the card has 
been attempted and processed, but before the CPI displays its own Order 
Confirmation screen to the cardholder. As such, the Post URL is not called 
by a browser post – the post back process is completely server side."

Comment: Well, I have different returnurl and post url. When the payment is processed and it takes me back to the returnurl. Can I not access the post data? i.e. `transcationstatus`? In the docs there's a 'PHP Response Handling Script' which seems to suggest I can access these values.

Comment: yeh you should be able to access those in the script that sits on your post_url. That is where the response handling script should be. As said above it is useful to send yourself a mail from that script for testing as it happens in the background so you cannot see it in the browser. eg. mail('your_email_address', 'epdq_testing', print_r($_POST, true)); Your response handler should store the results of the transaction, then when the user is returned to your site (returnurl) you can lookup the results and display them to the user

Comment: Just had a look at their example scripts and what they do is store the transaction results in a file in the post_url script, and then pull those out using the oid in the returnurl script. Obviously you should rather store the details in your db.

Comment: Yeah got an email back. It seems it makes a request to the post url before you leave the payment process. I thought it would call it when you are redirected to the returnurl. So I'll do the db stuff before i get to the returnurl